# Dropbox - update file in local folder instead of overwriting

Tags: file-management, dropbox

When I have a new version of a file (with the same exact file name), and I drop it into the dropbox.com online folder, the file updates, and **most importantly**, the share link stays the same.

However, if I do the same locally, the file gets overwritten, and the share link is severed!

I have a documentation tool that outputs new files regularly, and if I have it publish to the Dropbox folder, it overwrites the existing files, and the links (which were meant to be permalinks) become invalid.

I need a suggestion of how to go about updating files in bulk, and easily, aside from opening dropbox.com and dragging them in each time.

I should add that I need each link to reach a specific file, so linking to the folder does not help.

Or, alternatively, does anyone have a different product to recommend that supports what I'm looking for?

Comment: if you have a set of files, can't you share the folder instead of the specific documents? would that also sever the link?

Comment: @msb, I might be able to, but my aim is to share specific files only.

Comment: You could you setup a separate folder in Dropbox with of mirrors only the files you desire to share and use something like freefilesync to mirror the files automatically to shared folder.

Comment: @Damon, how would this help? Please elaborate.

Comment: @DAE It would allow you to segregate the specific files you want to share to a folder there in allowing you to share the folder of only segregated files instead of the original folder where you may not want to share everything.

Comment: This can be a problem of the documentation tool. One strategy to write a new file content is to create a temp file, output content, delete the old, an rename the temp file. This avoids incomplete content. You can check if your tool follows this pattern and try to change its behavior if possible. Or you can write a backend the actually updates the file with the tool output.

Comment: @Damon - thanks, but as i've since clarified in my question, I need each link to reach a specific file, so linking to a folder doesn't serve me.

Comment: @harper, even if I take files manually, the windows file replace functionality seems to erase the file and the link doesn't carry over

Comment: What is "Windows file replace functionality"? Do you mean Windows Explorer? I wouldn't trust it and create this with W32 API, i.e. using CreateFile with OPEN_EXISTING and WriteFile.

Comment: @harper - i mean what happens when you paste a file in a folder and Windows prompts you to replace, not paste, or keep both

Comment: I am convinced that the Explorer follows the described pattern, with reason. The pattern avoids incompletely written files. This should be a goal for a file explorer.

Comment: See here for a bug report on their forums: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Sharing-and-collaboration/Can-I-replace-a-file-but-keep-the-same-link-The-link-has-already/td-p/61254 If you're having problems you might be best contacting their support.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what I can say about cloud storage is, If you deal with the same file name or same folder names. You must love conflicts.
A lot of time I get Conflicts ,Update Errors , Sync problems same way.
I use both GoogleDrive , OneDrive and Dropbox. what I can say about these three is OneDrives engine's copes with a lot of situation better then others. It my personal experience.

---

About your situation, A link is created to a file in the storage not the name. It creates a link with both fileName,Some Guid Variable and TimeStamp. Most of the time it mixes these three.
So Your File Name stays same but because other parameters changed so the link is corrupted.Because you refer to an old file and it is overwritten  , do not exist.
So the Conclusion is as far as I know you must create links everytime you change  a file ,there is no practical solution for this.

But if you create a directory with the same name as your file and with the extension. You can manage the situation just you will have a lot of  unnecessary folder for exactly each of file you want the link to be active.

Comment: thanks for sharing your experience. As I mentioned though, its a feasible solution to manually drag-and-drop the files into the dropbox browser window. That way they do update